# Setting a field as a hyperlink in a list

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, column, hyperlink

I'm attempting to use a calculated column to set the field as a hyperlink.  Currently, I'm using this code.

```
="<a href='"&%URL_Field_Name%&"'> "&[%field_name%]&"</a>"
```

So, If I enter in my desired URL and the respective field name, then it should look something like this:

```
="<a href='"&%http://cas/customers/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/american%20standard.aspx_Hyperlink Test%&"'> "&[%Hyperlink_Test%]&"</a>"
```

However, I'm getting syntax errors so obviously something is being done wrong here.  Any ideas are appreciated.

FWIW: I'm using Sharepoint Foundation.  Is it possible that Microsoft patched this work-around out to get users to switch to enterprise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a solution.

Our hyperlink needed to be an image AND a clickable link.  By simply creating a **multiple lines of text** column type, we can insert the needed image and the respective link.

1. You need to create **multiple lines of text** column type.  This can be done by going to your site settings, choosing **site libraries and lists** and then choosing which list you'd like to modify.
2. Once in the settings of that list, go ahead and scroll down near  the bottom and click **create column**.
3. Once in the create column page, select **multiple lines of text**.
   [image]
4. Finish the initial creation process of your column, and then navigate to the list that you just added the column to.  You'll need to click **edit this list**, then click inside of the newly created field.  At the top, select the **insert tab**, then click **picture**.
5. Re-select the image, click insert again, click **link**.  You can leave the description blank if you'd like.  Insert your desired link and you're all set.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the %. This should work:

`="<a href='"&[URL_Field_Name]&"'> "&[field_name]&"</a>"`

Comment: Actually, now i'm getting this: The formula contains a circular reference (the calculated column refers to itself).  You must remove or change the circular reference.